# Which implementation to use when creating a List from Iterable

Tags: java, performance, list, memory-management

I find myself frequently doing the following:

```
Iterator<A> itr = iterableOfA.getIterator();
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>(); // how about LinkedList?
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    B obj = iter.next().getB();
    list.add(obj);
}
someMethod(list); // this method takes an Iterable
```

I have no idea just how many elements are likely to be in `iterableOfA` — could be 5, could be 5000. In this case, would `LinkedList` be a better implementation to use here (since `list.add(obj)` would then be O(1))? As it stands, if `iterableOfA` has 5000 elements, this will lead to many resizings of backing array of `list`.

Other option is to do:

```
Iterator<A> itr = iterableOfA.getIterator();
int size = Iterables.size(iterableOfA); // from Guava
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>(size);
// and the rest...
```

This means double iteration of `iterableOfA`. Which option would be best when the size of the iterable is unknowns and can vary wildly:

1. Just use `ArrayList`.
2. Just use `LinkedList`.
3. Count the elements in `iterableOfA` and allocate an `ArrayList`.

### Edit 1

To clarify some details:

1. I am optimizing primarily for performance and secondarily for memory usage.
2. `list` is a short-lived allocation as at the end of the request no code should be holding a reference to it.

### Edit 2

For my specific case, I realized that `someMethod(list)` doesn't handle an iterable with greater than 200 elements, so I decided to go with `new ArrayList<>(200)` which works well enough for me.

However, in the general case I would have preferred to implement the solution outlined in the accepted answer (wrap in a custom iterable, obviating the need for allocating a list).

All the other answers gave valuable insight into how suitable `ArrayList` is compared to `LinkedList`, so on behalf of the general SO community I thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would completely skip copying the elements to a new collection.

We have utility code for easily wrapping Iterators into Iterables and Filter for converting between types, but the gist of it is:

```
final Iterable<A> iofA ... ;
Iterable<B> iofB = new Iterable<B>() {
  public Iterator<B> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<B>() {
      private final Iterator<A> _iter = iofA.iterator();
      public boolean hasNext() { return _iter.hasNext(); }
      public B next() { return _iter.next().getB(); }
    };
  }
};
```

No additional storage, etc. necessary.

Comment: Though this isn't a direct answer to the question I had asked, it is a smarter solution that I had been thinking of, hence marking it as the accepted answer. This doesn't lessen the answers by others.

Answer (score 2):

> Which option would be best when the size of the iterable is unknowns and can vary wildly

It depends what you are optimizing for.

- If you are optimizing for performance, then using `ArrayList` is probably faster.  Even though `ArrayList` will need to resize the backing array, it does this using an exponential growth pattern.  However, it depends on the overheads of iteration.
- If you are optimizing for long-term memory usage, consider using `ArrayList` followed by `trimToSize()`.
- If you are optimizing for peak memory usage, the "count first" approach is probably the best.  (This assumes that you can iterate twice.  If the iterator is actually a wrapper for a lazy calculation .... this may be impossible.)
- If you are optimizing to reduce GC, then "count first" is probably best, depending on the details of the iteration.

In all cases you would be advised to:

1. Profile you application *before* you spend more time on this issue.  In a lot of cases you will find that this is simply not worth your effort in optimizing.
2. Benchmark the two alternatives that you are considering, using the classes and typical data structures from your application.

---

> As it stands, if `iterableOfA` has 5000 elements, this will lead to many resizings of backing array of list.

The `ArrayList` class resizes to a new size that proportional to the current size.  That means that the number of resizings is `O(logN)`, and the overall cost of `N` list append calls is `O(N)`.

Comment: Addendum for the curious: ArrayList is faster due to its more compact memory layout, where an additional entry consumes a mere 8 bytes (or 4 with compressed oops), in contrast to a LinkedList, where each new entry requires an additional Node object of about 32 bytes (or about 16 bytes with compressed oops). That is, even if the array overallocates by a factor of 2 (worst case) it still takes half as much memory as the LinkedList would.

Answer (score 1):

3rd option is not bad. For getting size, most of the collections just return the counter that they maintain internally...it does not iterate through the entire list. It depends on the implementation, but all the java.util.xxx collection classes does that way.

If u know what are the potential types of "iterableOfA", u can check how they are doing size.

If "iterableOfA" is going to be some custom implementation and you are not sure how size is done, linkedlist would be safer. That is because ur size varies and potential of resizing is higher, hence u will not get a predictable performance.

Also not sure what operations you are performing in the collection that you are filling "B", your choice would depend on that also.

Comment: Okay, you are using - Iterables.size(iterableOfA); // from Guava...It would still be using the size() method of underlying collection so it depends on what is the underlying collection. If it is any of those java collections, it should be fine....but if it is custom implementation, then will have to check.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` is a cache-hostile memory eating moster, which its father (Joshua Bloch) [regrets](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248).

I'd bet, it's not faster in your case as `ArrayList` resizing is optimized and takes amortized `O(1)` per element, too.

Basically, the only case when `LinkedList` is faster, is the following loop:

```
for (Iterator<E> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    E e = it.next();
    if (someCondition(e)) e.remove();
}
```

---

> As it stands, if iterableOfA has 5000 elements, this will lead to many resizings of backing array of list.

Many is something like `log(5000 / 10) / log(1.5)`, i.e., 15. But the count doesn't matter much as the last resizings dominate. You'll be copying each object reference maybe twice, that's cheap.

*Assuming you'll be doing anything with the list, it's very cheap .*

---

Iterating just to find out the number of elements might help in some cases, but the speed depends on the input `Iterable`. So unless you need the speed really badly and you know that the input is never really slow, I'd refrain from such an optimization.