# Java: Does it make sense to create LinkedList and convert it to an ArrayList for sorting?

Tags: java, performance, sorting, arraylist, linked-list

The title says it all. I have to add several thousand objects to a List and then sort them. For now I thought (since adding something to a LinkedList is considerably faster) I'd use a LinkedList for creation and then make a new ArrayList like so:

```
LinkedList<Foo> createList = new LinkedList<Foo>();
// add stuff
ArrayList<Foo> returnList = new ArrayList<Foo>(createList);
Collections.sort(returnList);
return returnList;
```

My question is:
Is this method really faster or even slower than just adding the objects directly to an ArrayList?
Or, I know the rough number of objects to add. Is an ArrayList with initial capacity faster?

Comment: Don't worry about performance until you have a performance problem that you can actually measure. Focus on readable code instead. In this case, the `LinkedList` will probably be _slower_.

Comment: "since adding something to a LinkedList is considerably faster" source?

Comment: Will your collection of `Foo` objects contain duplicates or will the collection be distinct?

Comment: @BasilBourque only unique ones

Comment: @AndyTurner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656471/performance-differences-between-arraylist-and-linkedlist only one example. There are many others out there

Comment: @FlorianBecker I wouldn't say the linked question says that definitively. Here is a preso about performance comparison of the two, in which ArrayList squarely wins: https://twitter.com/dblevins/status/919410565264506880?s=19. The tweet thread here includes Josh Bloch (the author of Java's LinkedList) saying he never actually uses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to two questions:
1. What's the difference between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, which one is faster for insertion?
2. Which one is faster in sorting?

For question 1, the essential difference between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` is the data structure. `ArrayList` uses an array inside and good at random access(O(1)). On the other hand, `LinkedList` in good at delete and insert items(O(1). You can find more [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/difference-between-arraylist-and-linkedlist-in-java/#:~:text=Reason%3A%20ArrayList%20maintains%20index%20based,elements%20for%20searching%20an%20element.)
Back to the question, because we don't need to insert by index here. 
So `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` both O(1) operation. But `LinkedList` will cause more memory because of the data structure, and `ArrayList` will cause more time if it needs to scale capacity(set a large enough initial capacity will help speed up the insertion).

For question 2, you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069370/is-an-arraylist-or-a-linkedlist-better-for-sorting)
`ArrayList` is better for sorting.

In conclusion, I think you should stick with ArrayList, no need to import `LinkedList` here.

Answer (score 0):

Forget `LinkedList`. It's much slower except when you need things like `.add(0, item)` or `remove(0)` where the `ArrayList` has quadratic complexity. As long as all you need is `.add(item)` and `sort`, the `ArrayList` wins hands down.

See also [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38933563/581205).

---

Note also that the copying into the `ArrayList` is questionable as `Collections.sort` [used to copy it itself to an array](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L153). Since Java 8, the internal array of the `ArrayList` [gets sorted directly](https://github.com/unofficial-openjdk/openjdk/blob/jdk/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L1718).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> Does it make sense to create LinkedList and convert it to an ArrayList for sorting?

No, that conversion does not make sense. Not from what we see in the empirical benchmarking test shown below.

➥ Both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` take about the same amount of time to sort a list of 100,000 random hex strings.

## Beware of premature optimization

Never intuit performance problems. Programmers of every skill/experience level are notoriously bad at spotting bottlenecks in their code base. This is especially true with the highly-tuned Java compilers and  Java Virtual Machine implementations. Worrying about performance without actual evidence is known as the trap of *premature optimization*.

## No difference: Sorting 100,000 element `ArrayList` *or* `LinkedList` takes around 0.05 seconds

Doing a quick-and-dirty benchmark test shows that indeed you should not be spending time focused on performance of sorting performance of [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) versus [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html). Assuming my benchmark code is valid, the performance of either list is nearly the same. I also tried two implementations of [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html), [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) and [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html), since [you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62227775/java-does-it-make-sense-to-create-linkedlist-and-convert-it-to-an-arraylist-for/62240194#comment110064527_62227775) your collection of objects is distinct (no duplicate objects). Each of the four collections take at most a tenth of a second to populate and sort 100,000 random `String` elements.

The results are around **half of a tenth of a second for the combination of populating and sorting a collection of over 100,000**. Since your work involves only 10,000, we are talking about a tiny fraction of a second. Unless you are doing thousands/millions of these operations per second, this populating & sorting of a list has no significant impact on your app.

> durationArrayList = PT0.038510117S
>
> durationLinkedList = PT0.045435537S
>
> durationTreeSet = PT0.067535504S
>
> durationConcurrentSkipListSet = PT0.104006783S

Here is another run.

> durationArrayList = PT0.031999744S
>
> durationLinkedList = PT0.037321294S
>
> durationTreeSet = PT0.065598175S
>
> durationConcurrentSkipListSet = PT0.084586606S

Those results come from running inside IntelliJ 2020.2, compiled via Maven for Java 14, using AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7), on a Mac mini (2018) with 3 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU without Hyper-Threading, 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4, macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Notice that the `ConcurrentSkipListSet` takes the longest time. That class is designed for concurrent ([thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)) use. So the longer execution time is justified, if you need concurrent protection of your collection. Otherwise, if not accessing the collection across threads, use one of the other three collection types instead.

Here is the benchmark code. Please review carefully, as I threw this together quickly, and with all the cutting-and-pasting, I may well have made a mistake.

The testing code call this `timeout` method to sleep several seconds, in an attempt to let the [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) run (assuming the JVM respected by request to run gc cycle).

```
private void timeout ( )
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis( 5 ) );
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the testing code.

We start with a list of 100,000 strings, each the [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation of a [Version 4 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)), where 122 of the [128 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit_computing) are [randomly generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation). Example value: `0063a1f3-39d0-421b-80ab-70e4e1726904`.

```
System.out.println( "INFO - Beginning the speed tests for sorting ArrayList, LinkedList, TreeSet, and ConcurrentSkipListSet." );

System.gc();
this.timeout();

// --------|  setup  | ---------------------
final int LIMIT = 100_000;
List < String > tempList = new ArrayList <>();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < LIMIT ; i++ )
{
    tempList.add( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
}
final List < String > sourceList = List.copyOf( tempList );  // List.copyOf makes an unmodifiable list.
tempList = null ;

{
    // Warmup
    final List < String > warmUpArrayList = new ArrayList <>( sourceList );
    Collections.sort( warmUpArrayList );
    final List < String > warmUpLinkedList = new LinkedList <>( sourceList );
    Collections.sort( warmUpLinkedList );
    final SortedSet < String > warmUpSortedSet = new TreeSet <>( sourceList );
    final SortedSet < String > warmUpConcurrentSkipListSet = new ConcurrentSkipListSet <>( sourceList );
}

// Pause
System.gc();
this.timeout();

long start, stop;

// --------|  ArrayList  | ---------------------
start = System.nanoTime();

List < String > arrayList = new ArrayList <>();
arrayList.addAll( sourceList );
Collections.sort( arrayList );

stop = System.nanoTime();
Duration durationArrayList = Duration.ofNanos( stop - start );

arrayList = null;
// Pause
System.gc();
this.timeout();

// --------|  LinkedList  | ---------------------
start = System.nanoTime();

List < String > linkedList = new LinkedList <>();
linkedList.addAll( sourceList );
Collections.sort( linkedList );

stop = System.nanoTime();
Duration durationLinkedList = Duration.ofNanos( stop - start );

linkedList = null;
// Pause
System.gc();
this.timeout();


// --------|  TreeSet  | ---------------------
start = System.nanoTime();

TreeSet < String > treeSet = new TreeSet <>();  // Implements `SorteSet`.
treeSet.addAll( sourceList );

stop = System.nanoTime();
Duration durationTreeSet = Duration.ofNanos( stop - start );

treeSet = null;
// Pause
System.gc();
this.timeout();


// --------|  ConcurrentSkipListSet  | ---------------------
start = System.nanoTime();

ConcurrentSkipListSet < String > concurrentSkipListSet = new ConcurrentSkipListSet <>();  // Implements `SorteSet`.
concurrentSkipListSet.addAll( sourceList );

stop = System.nanoTime();
Duration durationConcurrentSkipListSet = Duration.ofNanos( stop - start );

concurrentSkipListSet = null;
// Pause
System.gc();
this.timeout();


// --------|  reporting  | ---------------------

System.out.println( "durationArrayList = " + durationArrayList );
System.out.println( "durationLinkedList = " + durationLinkedList );
System.out.println( "durationTreeSet = " + durationTreeSet );
System.out.println( "durationConcurrentSkipListSet = " + durationConcurrentSkipListSet );
```